# Alternative to Plotly and Google Maps for Angular app

Tags: maps, angular

I need to draw several arrows on a satellite view map in a Angular application I'm developing.
We use plotly throughout the app however I have the issue that the traces rendering becomes unacceptably slow when there are several traces. Every arrow I put on the map is a trace.

I tried AGM (Angular Google Maps) and it works perfectly for my application, however there is road block for me to use AGM which is the fact that every arrow shows up in the HTML. We cannot have that happen since the data we are showing are proprietary.

Is there any alternative out there as maps utility? Here is a screen shot of what my final result should look like.

Thanks

[image]